# Do we need the [bypass] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

A few days ago, the tag [bypass](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bypass) was created. Is this a tag we actually need or can I kill it?

My philosophy on tags is that they need to be at least a little specific. Every security question is in some way about either how you bypass protections or how you stop people from bypassing protecions. I don't think questions that will be tagged with this tag will be different from those that are not in any meaningful way.

What do you think?

Comment: I think it's way too broad of a tag; based on 2/3 of the tagged questions, I think it should be merged with any tags for AV evasion, if they exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the tag in question doesn't have any associated questions, it should be deleted.

But even if it were not empty, bypass is a bit too ambiguous. Can you be an expert at bypassing stuff? Not really, because it could mean bypassing AV, bypassing blacklists, bypassing authentication, etc...

It's not a good tag and should be yeeted.